# Calculate date based on given time

Tags: php, date, time

I went through a project which I need to set a recall time for an event. the recall time is set to 1 day and some hours before the event happen. I  calculate event date and recall time like this:

```
$now = time();
$days_to_event = 24 ; //(I set an input for it in form)
$event_time = $now + $days_to_event * 3600;
$difference = 24*3600 + time('h')*3600 + time('i')*60;
$recall_time = $event_time - $difference;
```

I was wondering if I could create a function which takes `$recall_time` and calculates the date and outputs it.

Any useful idea for simplifying the project is a great help for me.

Thank you my friends.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the DateTime class (http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)?

Comment: I checked the link. DateTime class is much better to work with.Maybe next time I use your good advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer you are looking for maybe is

```
 echo date('Y-m-d H:i',$recall_time);
```

Answer (score 1):

time() function return timestamp format, You need date() function to get hour and minute.

```
$now = time();
$days_to_event = 24; //(I set an input for it in form)
$event_time = $now + $days_to_event * 3600;
$difference = 24 * 3600 + date('h') * 3600 + date('i') * 60;
$recall_time = $event_time - $difference;

echo date('Y-m-d H:i', $now) . '<br>';
echo date('Y-m-d H:i', $event_time) . '<br>';
echo date('Y-m-d H:i', $recall_time) . '<br>';
```